# ESXI 5.5 Doesn't see full hard drive

Tags: vmware-esxi, hard-drive, sata

I have an ESXI 5.5 host which I've had up for a while (whitebox build) and I've recently replaced one of the internal hard drives due to failure (not raid, directly connected to the SATA controller).  The new drive is EXACTLY the same as the one I had in it before, same build, same size etc...  However ESXI seems to think its a 3GB hard drive, while its actually a 3TB hard drive.  When I look at it through VSPHERE I can't do anything with it like detach it or format it or anything.  Am I missing something ?  It seems like I've done this before without any trouble and I can't really remember doing anything special I those instances .  I simply want to format it as one 3TB partition, but can't figure out how.  This is a standalone install of ESXI (the free version) so I don't have Vcentre or anything, but I do have VSPHERE client and VMware workstation to manage it as well as SSH access of course.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove this disk from the Data store and add it again. From your Vsphere Client click on your VMWare host --> Configuration--> Add Storage --> Select storage type Disk/LUN --> 
In the menu Select Disk/LUN, you should see your disk and description. Is Capacity description correct? Next in File system version choose VMFS-5 --> Next--> Next--> formating option, choose Maximum available space --> Next -->Finish.

Comment: That's the problem, I can do all that...but VSPHERE thinks the drive is only 3gb.  I'm not having trouble creating a datastore..this is before I even add it as a datastore.

Comment: Can you connect this disk to another computer and check if the disk size is only 3GB?

Comment: I suppose I could do that...that's a pretty solid plan :)

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a bum hard drive.. thanks for all the responses.